# Covariance of the least squares error equal to var*I?

Tags: least-squares, covariance, generalized-least-squares

In what case is the covariance of the least squares error equal to $cov(e)= \sigma^2 I $?

Comment: Please clarify whether you mean the random term in the model or the residual in a least squares fit.  If it's the former, then the answer is trivial: whenever that assumption is made.

Comment: @whuber e = y-yhat

Comment: Do you include a constant term ("intercept") in your model?